# Why does ngdocs generate 0 files?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jsdoc

I have set up an extremely simple project to test out grunt-ngdocs (https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-ngdocs).  However, when I try to generate documentation, it does not recognize any comments.  Why?!  Help!

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    ngdocs: {
      options:{dest: 'docs'},
      api:{
        src:['someCode.js'],
        title:'API Documentation'
      }
    }
  });

  // Load the plugin that provide tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ngdocs');

};
```

someCode.js

```
/**
 *
 * This is a sample function
 * @param x
 * @returns {number}
 */
var myFunc = function(x){
  return 2*x;
};
```

Console output:

```
slc058:ngDocPlay selah$ grunt ngdocs
Running "ngdocs:api" (ngdocs) task
Generating Documentation...
DONE. Generated 0 pages in 7ms.

Done, without errors.
```

Comment: What does it have to do with jsdoc?

Comment: ngDoc is built upon jsdoc and the syntax is very similar

Comment: Just to clarify, I consider ngDoc a super customized version of jsdoc

Answer (score 2):

I modified someCode.js to be the following and then it worked!

someCode.js

```
/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name myFunc
 * @description
 * This is a sample function
 * @param {number} x - any number, don't matter which
 */
var myFunc = function(x){
  return 2*x;
};
```

Comment: The issue was that the description was missing. ngdocs requires the param type, name and the description.